# Solution of $ny=x$ in abelian group exists if $O(x) < \infty$ and $GCD(n,O(x)) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $x\in G$ is an element of finite order $m$. Then for every $n$ such that $GCD(n,m) = 1$ there exist $y \in G$ such that $ny=x$.

How do I prove this one? Is the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups applicable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bachet-Bézout theorem: if $\gcd(n,m)=1$, then $1=an+bm$ for some integers $a$ and $b$.

Thus
$$
x=1x=(an+bm)x=n(ax)+b(mx)=n(ax)
$$
and you can take $y=ax$.

Comment: Wow, this is surprisingly simple! Thank you for such elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by considering only $\langle x\rangle$, the subgroup generated by $x$. Using Lagrange's theorem tells us that the order of this subgroup divides $O(x)$ and is hence coprime to $n$ as well. This reduces the problem to the case of an abelian group generated by a single element, which is reasonably easy to solve. Notice that this solution does not require that the group is abelian.

It is also possible to do it with the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups as you suggest; note that the direct product of two groups in which $n^{th}$ roots exist also has $n^{th}$ roots.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely gives a nudge in the right direction. Btw, what do you think of the previous answer?